# $n\in \mathbb{N} :\ \ \ \ \sin (n \pi +x)=(-1)^n \sin x $

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that :

> **Theorem 1**
>   $$n\in \mathbb{N} :\ \ \ \ \sin (n \pi +x)=(-1)^n \sin x  $$
>
> $$n\in \mathbb{N} :\ \ \ \ \sin \left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi  +x\right)=(-1)^n \cos x  $$

---

My Try :

I know that :

$$\text{if} : x+y=\pi \to \sin x=\sin y$$

$$\text{if} : x+y= \frac{\pi}{2} \to \sin x=\cos x$$

So we have :

$$\text{if} : x+y=\pi\\y=\pi -x \to \sin x=\sin (\pi-x)$$

$$\text{if} : x+y= \frac{\pi}{2}\\ y= \frac{\pi}{2}-x \to \sin x=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$$

Now how do I prove Theorem 1?

Comment: How about induction?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(\pi n+x)=\sin\pi n\cos{x}+\cos\pi n\sin{x}=(-1)^n\sin{x}.$$

$$\sin (\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi  +x)=\sin\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi\cos{x}+\cos\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi\sin{x}=(-1)^n \cos x$$

Comment: why ?$$\sin\pi n\cos{x}+\cos\pi n\sin{x}=(-1)^n\sin{x}$$

Comment: @Almot1960 Because $\sin\pi n=0$ and $\cos\pi n=(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\sin(n \pi + x) &=\sin(n\pi)\cos(x)+\cos(n\pi)\sin(x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin  (n\pi +x)=\underset { =0 }{ \underbrace { \sin { \left( n\pi  \right)  }  }  } \cos { \left( x \right)  } +\underset { ={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n } }{ \underbrace { \cos { \left( n\pi  \right)  }  }  } \sin { \left( x \right)  } ={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n }\sin { \left( x \right)  } $$

Comment: why ? $$\cos (n\pi)=(-1)^n$$

Comment: Because ,$$n=1\quad \Rightarrow \cos { \pi  } =-1\\ n=2\quad \Rightarrow \cos { 2\pi =1 } \\ n=3\quad \Rightarrow \cos { 3\pi =\cos { \left( 2\pi +\pi  \right) =\cos { \pi  } = } -1 } \\ n=4\quad \Rightarrow \cos { 4\pi =1 } $$ combine all together we get $$\cos { \left( n\pi  \right)  } ={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n }$$